# Play and pause on webp animated images

Tags: javascript, animation, webp

I need to implement play and pause control on web animated images which should play and pause on the same frame itself. Please tell me the solution if anybody know about this

Comment: Convert it to a video?

Comment: For the size consumption i have come to webp animation instead of using video.

Comment: well you probably did something wrong in your calculations or conversion, videos should be smaller than animated images.

Comment: Webp animated images taken smaller size than video of same file

Comment: Once again you probably did something wrong. Check [this link](https://corydowdy.com/blog/apng-vs-webp-vs-gif) in the section "What Should You Use".

Answer (score 5):

## Introduction

**I was searching for myself an answer a moment ago, when** i found your Question and already had some **approaches** to it, so **i thought to share them** with a post-answer [...]

- ### Approach 1

**The [freezeframe.js](https://github.com/ctrl-freaks/freezeframe.js/) Approach**, that works with **webp** too.
*<sub>(but without play&pause functionality on the same frame)</sub>* 
 **<sub>WEBP DEMO</sub>** `codepen.io/giorgosxou/pen/MWeqzgr`

- ### Approach 2

**The "Gif player-parser" Approach**: Could be done by creating an alternative [LC-GIF-Player](https://github.com/LCweb-ita/LC-GIF-Player) [(gif-demo)](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/lc-gif-player/) or [gif-player](https://github.com/CaptainCodeman/gif-player) [(gif-demo)](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/captaincodeman/gif-player) that would (parse) work with webp.

- ### Approach 3

**My Approach** kinda like the first approach, was to just change url from a static image to webp on hover or click (although i haven't implemented it yet.. Because for now i just removed them as they are not actually THAT important to me, most probably i will use gifs and aproach-2 )

## Outro

**I know it's not a solution to the question** but definitely some kind of a helpful answer to those looking for an approach [...]